# What is the best way to troubleshoot these Plesk errors messages?

Tags: apache, centos, system-administration, plesk, mediatemple

I get the following error regularly on my MediaTemple DV server.

```
 Web Server (Apache) on myrootdomain.com is down
 Web Server (Apache) on myrootdomain.com has been started

 Plesk Web Server on myrootdomain.com is down
 Plesk Web Server on myrootdomain.com has been started
```

I get at least one, sometimes more, every single day. MediaTemple aren't being very helpful as DV are self-managed. So it falls to me to be the sysadmin. Any help would be great! I have some important sites running on this server and every time I get these errors I get about 10 minutes downtime whilst Apache restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a linux system, you might want to try lsof (list open files).
See what files get accessed on the moment your server crashes.

Be careful though, lsof can generate a lot of output, so you better run it
trough a pipe. lsof | egrep -i (apache|plesk)

Or whatever the name is of the process.

Comment: How do I find the name of the process?